# Is there a way to check Linux server logs error messages and exceptions using automation test scenario itself once I run an automated test scenario

Tags: java, linux, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a Java/Selenium/TestNG test suite. I use this test suite to test the functional test scenarios. Although test assertions pass, the system throws sometimes exceptions and error messages in the back-end. Therefore, I need to verify that there are no exceptions or error messages thrown respective scenario. My application is running on Linux back end. Is there a way to capture exceptions or errors and make sure no exceptions or error in the back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the log file using file transfer protocol to your local machine, and then parse the log file for the exceptions/ errors

Copying the log file can be done by using pscp tool something similar to this

```
pscp.exe -pw {Password} {username}@{Host name}:{Log file location} {Location to save file}
```

**pscp.exe can be found in the installed folder of Putty (C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY)**

Depends on the file, you can have the parser something similar to this

```
public void parseFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File({filelocation}));
    while(scan.hasNext()){
        String line = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().toString();
        if(line.contains({Exception Details})){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad it is helpful :)